# Bootstrap modal scroll bar appears and disappears after triggering the another modal

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

I tried many things but none worked. Hence posting the question, if found duplicate then I am sorry.

I have an issue with bootstrap modal scrolling, here is the scenario:

- I have 2 Modals: Modal-1 and Modal-2.
- When the user is filling the information in Modal-1, he has an option to click on a button in Modal-1 and go to Modal-2 and come back to Modal-1 again after completed filling Modal-2 information.
- Initially when Modal-1 is triggered then I get the scrollbar in Modal-1 as the information in the modal is quite large.
- When User goes to Modal-2 from Modal-1 and comes back to Modal-1 then the scrollbar appears for a fraction of second and then disappears due to which 'SAVE' button is not visible to user unless he zooms-out.

I am not understanding how come the Scrollbar visible initially and it disappears later. I tried couple of things but none worked.

I have following styles written for the modal in my Stylesheet:

```
.modal { overflow: visible; }
.modal-body { overflow-y: visible !important; }
```

My Modal-1 headers are as follows:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EventModalForm">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Can someone help me resolve this issue?

Comment: I have tried to reproduce this though it seems to work fine for me, are you sure it isn't just your browser/device?

Comment: @Skully Thanks a lot for taking your time and checking this. In my case it was not working. After bit more research I added the following style to my main div of the modal `style="overflow-y: auto;"` and its now working fine. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

After adding following style ' style="overflow-y: auto;"' its working fine now:

```
<div class="modal fade" id="EventModalForm" style="overflow-y: auto;">
    <div class="modal-dialog" style="max-height:100%; max-width:100%;">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```